# AudioQueueDispose crashes in IOS 6, works fine in IOS 5

Tags: ios, streaming, soundcloud

I'm streaming music from SoundCloud, using their streaming APIs, which in turn uses Apple's AudioToolbox framework. You can find the git repository [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper).

The app was streaming fine using ios 5 and below. Now with ios 6 I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS anytime an AudioQueue is disposed via [AudioQueueDispose](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html). I've tried commenting out this line; sure enough it doesn't crash anymore, but obviously my audio streams keep playing and never get dealloc'd.

I'm not really sure what could be causing this. Is this a bug that needs to be reported with Apple? Or some new feature in ios 6 that inadvertently causes the audioQueue to be referenced somewhere after it has been disposed? Has anyone noticed behavior like this?

Comment: you'll probably have more luck with this in the iOS6 section of the [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1):

AudioQueueDispose will work in iOS6 devices without fail. You have to pass true as second parameter for AudioQueueDispose. Then its asynchronously stop the queue. But the problem is same thing is not working in iOS 6.1 devices. Can anybody help me for this issue.Thanks for advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Please let me know if you figured this out

Comment: Finally i got the solution..i set the condition in "MyInputBufferHandler" and when ever start the recording we need to set the device volume to zero..i hope this will help to you..